# Best way to extract a reference category from a glm model?

Tags: r, lm

I'm writing a function that accepts a `full` and a `reduced` `glm` object to summarize interaction results for a variable of interest `varofint` and the interaction variable `interaction_var` (by performing a `lrtest` and using `svycontrast` on the `full` object to extract results for `varofint` for each level of `interaction_var`). Sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(outcome=rbinom(100,1,.3),varofint=rnorm(100), interaction_var=sample(letters[1:3],100,replace=TRUE))

reduced <- glm(outcome~varofint+interaction_var,data=x)
full <- glm(outcome~varofint*interaction_var,data=x)
```

I'd like to know the best way to extract a reference category for said (`full`) glm model. I could obviously do something like

`levels(full$data$interaction_var)[1]`

but would this  be a "safe" method to extract a reference category given inputs to the `contrasts` argument? It seems like, given the option to select SAS contrast, this method could produce a level of `interactionv_var` that isn't the one used as a reference category in the model. Would the following be safer?

```
mf <- model.frame(full)
setdiff(rownames(contrasts(mf[, "interaction_var"])), colnames(contrasts(mf[, "interaction_var"])))
```

or similarly

```
names(which(apply(contrasts(mf[, "interaction_var"]),1,function(.v){all(.v==0)})))
```

Am I missing a simpler way to extract the reference category?

Comment: What if there is no reference category? A reference category applies to treatment contrasts only.

Comment: Ok that's a good start. So, the function should return an error if the corresponding interaction variable doesn't have treatment contrasts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function for this task:

```
refCat <- function(model, var) {
  cs <- attr(model.matrix(model), "contrasts")[[var]]
  if (is.character(cs)) {
    if (cs == "contr.treatment")
      ref <- 1
    else stop("No treatment contrast")
  }  
  else {
    zeroes <- !cs
    ones <- cs == 1
    stopifnot(all(zeroes | ones))
    cos <- colSums(ones)
    stopifnot(all(cos == 1))
    ros <- rowSums(ones)
    stopifnot(sum(!ros) == 1 && sum(ros) != ncol(cs))
    ref <- which(!ros)
  }
  return(levels(model$data[[var]])[ref])  
}
```

The function will stop if the variable `var` is not represented as treatment contrasts.

Examples:

```
refCat(reduced, "interaction_var")
# [1] "a"
refCat(full, "interaction_var")
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. In what situations would `is.character(cs)` be `FALSE`?

Comment: @Michael `cs` can be either a character string with the name of the contrast function, e.g., `contr.treatment`, or a numerical contrast matrix.

Comment: this would not work if relevel() has been used, right?

Comment: @Helen I did not try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late, but `dummy.coef()` could work... the first value in each variable element of its output is the reference category.

```
# R 4.0.0 data.frame() does not produce factors
x <- data.frame(
  outcome = rbinom(100, 1, .3),
  varofint = rnorm(100),
  interaction_var = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
reduced <- glm(outcome ~ varofint + interaction_var, data = x)
full <- glm(outcome ~ varofint * interaction_var, data = x)

d <- dummy.coef(full)
d
# Full coefficients are 
#                                                                 
# (Intercept):                    0.310136                        
# varofint:                    -0.07247677                        
# interaction_var:                       a           b           c
#                               0.00000000  0.07017833 -0.05891015
# varofint:interaction_var:              a           b           c
#                               0.00000000 -0.14824179 -0.04123618

d$interaction_var
#           a           b           c 
#  0.00000000  0.07017833 -0.05891015 
d$interaction_var[1]
# a 
# 0 
names(d$interaction_var[1])
# [1] "a"
```